# Python - list of character to hex

Tags: python

I'm new in python I need to convert a list of character to hex
for example
a = ['hello' , 'day' , 'night']

my output be like = [0x68656c6c6f, 0x646179 , 0x6e69676874]

Comment: How do you convert a character to hex? say "z" - what should it be in hex?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We're not here to write your code for you. It looks like you want to do some ASCII conversions, which can be done with the built-in Python functions `chr` and `ord`. Of course, these work on individual characters, so to operate on lists of strings you'll have to do some iteration. Give it a go yourself, and feel free to come back if you run into a specific issue. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['hello' , 'day' , 'night']

from binascii import hexlify

print([bytes(item, "utf-8").hex() for item in a])
print([hexlify(bytes(item, "utf-8")) for item in a])
```

this outputs

```
['68656c6c6f', '646179', '6e69676874']
[b'68656c6c6f', b'646179', b'6e69676874']
```

the first one is list of strings
the second one is list of bytes objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in hex() function by converting your `string` to `utf-8`

```py
a = ['hello' , 'day' , 'night']

for row in range(len(a)):
    a[row] = a[row].encode('utf-8').hex()

print(a)
```

Output:

```
['68656c6c6f', '646179', '6e69676874']
```